# 'mat-label' is not a known element Error in latest Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I got an error in my Angular Material:

```
compiler.js:466 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-label' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            [ERROR ->]<mat-label>Both a label and a placeholder</mat-label>
            <input matInput placeholder="Simple"):
```

Question:

Material Label is under MatFormFieldModule [Here's the link](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatLabel)

Now, what is the possible cause of the issue why Mat-Label is unknown to Angular Material.

Here is the HTML

> ```
> <mat-form-field>
>           <mat-label>Both a label and a placeholder</mat-label>
>           <input matInput placeholder="Simple placeholder">
> </mat-form-field>
> ```

Comment: Did you check your app settings and if you're importing `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` in `app.module.ts`? This should fix the issue and remove the error. `import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';` and then `schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],` in @NgModule({...., schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]})

Comment: @k.vincent, that works, but it shouldn't require that.
Updating Angular is full day work :( guys, you can do better

Comment: thank u @k.vincent that solve my problem

Comment: @CHAHISaad, glad it did help!

Comment: Wow, upgrading from v9 to v12 (got to v11 when I got this error).  Took me half a day to find this 'solution'.     Not sure why adding Custom_Elements_Schema works, but it resolved the error. 

Thanks @k.vincent

Answer (score 72):

If you have multiple modules make sure you're importing the `MatFormFieldModule` in every module. It's not sufficient to just import it in the root module.

For example, I have a CommonWidgetsModule which contains some common widgets (my own) and you'll see I'm importing `MatFormFieldModule` and `MatInputModule`

```
// common-widgets.module.ts
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule,

    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,

    // import other MatModules...

  ],
  declarations: DECLARATIONS,
  exports: DECLARATIONS
})
export class CommonWidgetsModule { }
```

Comment: And you need to also add `MatInputModule` to avoid the error `Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.` (https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7704)

Comment: I also had to imort the submodule (here CommonWidgetsModule) in the app/root module. Also the component using the directive needs to be declared in the declarations of the submodule (here CommonWidgetsModule)

Answer (score 4):

Could also be that you forgot to add your component in your module (that is already importing `MatFormFieldModule` and `MatInputModule`.

Comment: saved me a headache, thanks mate :D

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are importing MatFormFieldModule in 'app.module.ts' or respective module's 'module.ts' file.

```
@NgModule({ 
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule, 
    MatFormFieldModule,
  ],
})
```

Comment: I have imported these 3 already. But the error is coming.

Answer (score 1):

be careful, if you want to use  in a dialog

@see https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

ok

```html
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Favorite Animal</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  My favorite animal is:
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span *ngIf="data.animal === 'panda'">&#10003;</span> Panda
    </li>
    <li>
      <span *ngIf="data.animal === 'unicorn'">&#10003;</span> Unicorn
    </li>
    <li>
      <span *ngIf="data.animal === 'lion'">&#10003;</span> Lion
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

ko

```html
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Favorite Animal</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-label>My favorite animal is:</mat-label>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span *ngIf="data.animal === 'panda'">&#10003;</span> Panda
    </li>
    <li>
      <span *ngIf="data.animal === 'unicorn'">&#10003;</span> Unicorn
    </li>
    <li>
      <span *ngIf="data.animal === 'lion'">&#10003;</span> Lion
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For this, you must create a new component, and not only a html template.

Answer (score 0):

I also found if you use the CLI and say skip-import. This will then result in the component not appear in your module. So it will not reference back to the imports for the mat label.

Answer (score 0):

in app.module.ts file add

```
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

imports:[
FormsModule
]
```

FormModule Includes all the Fields Related to Form

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have added the component name that uses `<mat-form-field>` and `<mat-label>` to **the main** `app.module.ts` declarations section. It is important to include the following modules as suggested in the previous answers: `MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, and MatFormFieldModule`.

Answer (score -1):

Add the import

```
import {ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Upgrade @angular/material to "5.2.0" and the problem will go away.