# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'mat-label' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to write aboute datepicker but I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'mat-label' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'mat-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mat-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

app.module.ts

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './pages/signup/signup.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './pages/profile/profile.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth/auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';
import { AlertModule } from '../app/_alert/alert.module';
import { HomeLayoutComponent } from './layouts/home-layout/home-layout.component';
import { LoginLayoutComponent } from './layouts/login-layout/login-layout.component';
import { StaffComponent } from './pages/staff/staff.component';
import { RegisterStaffComponent } from './pages/register-staff/register-staff.component';
import { AddTicketComponent } from './pages/add-ticket/add-ticket.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


export const router: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'staff',
        component: StaffComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'register-staff',
        component: RegisterStaffComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'add-ticket',
        component: AddTicketComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        component: ProfileComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'signup',
        component: SignupComponent
      },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    StaffComponent,
    RegisterStaffComponent,
    HomeLayoutComponent,
    LoginLayoutComponent,
    AddTicketComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AlertModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(router),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, AngularFireDatabase, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Are you using 'mat-select' it in some components which is in some other module ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import MatFormFieldModule for mat-label: [Form field appearance variants](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)

> The label for a form field can be specified by adding a mat-label element.

[This Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873128/mat-label-is-not-a-known-element-error-in-latest-angular-material) and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100238/mat-form-field-is-not-a-known-element-angular-5-material2/53208893) can be of help, too.